# Adding newline in the eventcreate description message while executing from java

Tags: java, windows, newline, event-log, stringescapeutils

We are trying to create windows eventlog by executing following command from java.
But unable add newline(\n) in the description(/d).

eventcreate /t error /id 100 /l myApp /SO "mysource" /d "this is 1st line of the log \n this is second line"

Executing above from java code : Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

1.Tried adding crl+l (^L) instead of \n but it works only from command line not from java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Finally got the solution:***

Instead of passing String as parameter to .exec() method we can pass Array of Strings.In this way log massage is identifying  \n as new line. Below code snippet now works.

```
String[] command = {"eventcreate", "/t", "error", "/id","100","/l", "CustomApp", "/SO","CustomSource","/d","this is 1st line of the log \n this is second line"};       
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```